# value storing in Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, android-studio

hi I want to save my high score value through shared preferences. but when I go to another activity and then get into same activity my high score value again begins with zero. I know its simple but I don't know what mistake I am doing. here is the example code.

```
    private static final String FORMAT = "%02d:%02d:%02d";
    int count = 0, high;
    int seconds , minutes;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        int savedPref = sharedPreferences.getInt("HighScore", 0);

        final TextView counter=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.taptimes);
        final TextView countdown=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.countdown);
        final TextView highScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.highScore);
        final Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.keypress);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                countClick();
            }

            private void countClick() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                count++;
                counter.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                if (count > high){

                    highScore.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                    high = count;

                    sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putInt("HighScore", high);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        });


        new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {//CountDownTimer(edittext1.getText()+edittext2.getText()) also parse it to long

             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                 countdown.setText("Time remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
              //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
             }

             public void onFinish() {
                 countdown.setText("Time Over!");
                 b1.setEnabled(false);
             }
            }
            .start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

Comment: for me this code works fine. If I am launching this activity multiple times, I am able to get the stored value. Maybe you are resetting the value in the Second Activity.

Comment: Second Activity has nothing to do with this.. I Don't know why not saving the value

Comment: Where are you using savedPref? Sorry, I'm in a mobile screen and I dont see any better, but I think you're not initializing count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OnCreate method I just missed these.. thanks for everyone

```
high = sharedPreferences.getInt("HighScore", 0);
 highScore.setText(Integer.toString(high));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please create common class for your Application Follow bellow Steps :

**Step 1:**

Create Application level Class

```
public class AppConfig extends Application {

private static AppConfig appInstance;
private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private static SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferencesEditor;
private static Context mContext;

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    appInstance = this;
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    sharedPreferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    setContext(getApplicationContext());

}

public static Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}

public static void setContext(Context mctx) {
    mContext = mctx;
}


public static AppConfig getAppInstance() {
    if (appInstance == null)
        throw new IllegalStateException("The application is not created yet!");
    return appInstance;
}

/**
 * Application level preference work.
 */
public static void preferencePutInteger(String key, int value) {
    sharedPreferencesEditor.putInt(key, value);
    sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
}

public static int preferenceGetInteger(String key, int defaultValue) {
    return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, defaultValue);
}

public static void preferencePutBoolean(String key, boolean value) {
    sharedPreferencesEditor.putBoolean(key, value);
    sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
}

public static boolean preferenceGetBoolean(String key, boolean defaultValue) {
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, defaultValue);
}

public static void preferencePutString(String key, String value) {
    sharedPreferencesEditor.putString(key, value);
    sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
}

public static String preferenceGetString(String key, String defaultValue) {
    return sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
}

public static void preferencePutLong(String key, long value) {
    sharedPreferencesEditor.putLong(key, value);
    sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
}

public static long preferenceGetLong(String key, long defaultValue) {
    return sharedPreferences.getLong(key, defaultValue);
}

public static void preferenceRemoveKey(String key) {
    sharedPreferencesEditor.remove(key);
    sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
}

public static void clearPreference() {
    sharedPreferencesEditor.clear();
    sharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
}
```

}

**Step 2:**

Define this class into Manifest.xml in Application tag like this

```
<application
    android:name=".AppConfig">
 </application>
```

**Step 3:**

You can use below code into your activity

```
AppConfig.preferencePutInteger("HighScore",yourScore);
AppConfig.preferenceGetInteger("HighScore", 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I see, is that you're not doing anything with `savedPref`:

```
int savedPref = sharedPreferences.getInt("HighScore", 0);
```

I think it should be:

```
high  = sharedPreferences.getInt("HighScore", 0);
```

Doesn't your IDE trigger a warning that `savedPref` is useless?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make a different class for shared preferences. I have been using this way for long time now and it is very easy maintenance for shared preferences. Here is my shared preference code

```
    public class AppSharedPreferences {

            private SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs;
            private SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;
            private static AppSharedPreferences appSharedPrefrence;

            public AppSharedPreferences(Context context) {
            this.appSharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("sharedpref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            this.prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
        }

        public AppSharedPreferences() {

        }

        public static AppSharedPreferences getsharedprefInstance(Context con) {
            if (appSharedPrefrence == null)
                appSharedPrefrence = new AppSharedPreferences(con);
            return appSharedPrefrence;
        }

        public SharedPreferences getAppSharedPrefs() {
            return appSharedPrefs;
        }

        public void setAppSharedPrefs(SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs) {
            this.appSharedPrefs = appSharedPrefs;
        }

        public SharedPreferences.Editor getPrefsEditor() {
            return prefsEditor;
        }

        public void Commit() {
            prefsEditor.commit();
        }

        public void clearallSharedPrefernce() {
            prefsEditor.clear();
            prefsEditor.commit();
        }
    public void setHelperId(int helperId)
    {
        this.prefsEditor=appSharedPrefs.edit();
        prefsEditor.putInt("helper_id", helperId);
        prefsEditor.commit();
    }
        public int getHelperId()
        {
            return appSharedPrefs.getInt("helper_id",0);
        }
}
```

for saving values in shared preference create get and set method as shown at end of code. Let all other methods of the code as it is.

And to use this code in your class just create an instance of shared preference in your class like this

```
appSharedPreferences= AppSharedPreferences.getsharedprefInstance(YourActivity.this) ;
```

Comment: is there any error I am doing wrong in my code? after restarting the app, high value is set to zero again

Comment: your value setting code is not working properly I think, as when you try to get it returns the default value

Comment: can you try with the code that I provided and see if it is working properly. It is a proper way and easy maintenance

Comment: i dont know how to implement this code in my project... i mean i dont know how to use that code

Comment: Just create a new class and copy paste that code. Also create new get and set method as I provided in the code for the value that you want to store

Answer (score 0):

i think the way you are retrieving and changing shared preferences might be the issue. Try fetching an instance of shared preferences as follows

```
 sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.MYUSERPREF, 0); //the 0 in the initialization is for private mode.
```

Also, an important thing to do is after you change the values and call `editor.commit();`
also call `editor.apply();` to save the changes to sharedPreferences

Comment: What exactly is happening? have you called `editor.apply();` everywhere where a commit is made?

Comment: yes i did but still not working.. i dont know why its not saving value

Comment: Can you update your code in the question to reflect exactly what is being done now?

Comment: I think ive figure it out.. you are checking  `if (count > high){}` but you variable high has not been initialized. You are allotting the value obtained from shared preferences to `int savedPref` . Maybe changing it to `int high = sharedPreferences.getInt("HighScore", 0);` will do the trick!

Comment: @shubhankars Just one little think, if you do `int high` you're declaring a local variable... apart from that little detail (remove the `int`) completely agree.

Comment: I agree .. realized that a while after posting.